# ServiceStack 5.0 AuthenticateAttribute.Execute() now returns a Task

Tags: c#, servicestack

I just upgraded to ServiceStack 5.0 from 4.0.

The breaking change is that now my Execute() method that overrides AuthenticateAttribute.Execute() doesn't work because `'AuthenticateAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Execute'`.

AuthenticateAttribute.Execute() now returns a `Task` (from `System.Threading.Tasks`):

```
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<ExecuteAsync>d__12))]
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto);
```

and I'm not sure how to rewrite my Execute() to return tasks...it's currently written as a method with return type `void`.

My code:

```
public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (HostContext.AppHost.HasValidAuthSecret(req))
        {
            return;
        }

        base.Execute(req, res, requestDto);
        if (res.IsClosed)
        {
            return; // AuthenticateAttribute already closed the request (ie auth failed)
        }

        IronUserSession session = req.GetSession() as IronUserSession;

        if (this.HasAnyRoles(req, session))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.DoHtmlRedirectIfConfigured(req, res))
        {
            return;
        }

        res.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        res.StatusDescription = ErrorMessages.InvalidRole.Localize(req);
        res.EndRequest();
    }
```

Is there a work-around for using ServiceStack's authentication the way I was previously?  Or is there a way to rewrite my code to return a task?  I'm not really sure what that task would even be...[their documentation is massive](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) but what it has on Execute() is almost nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely modify your method to return something like `await AuthProvider.HandleFailedAuth(authProviders[0], session, req, res);` which will return the task it seems you want to send.

Have you looked at the source code for the original method?

```
public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    if (AuthenticateService.AuthProviders == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The AuthService must be initialized by calling AuthService.Init to use an authenticate attribute");

    if (HostContext.HasValidAuthSecret(req))
        return;

    var authProviders = AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders(this.Provider);
    if (authProviders.Length == 0)
    {
        await res.WriteError(req, requestDto, $"No registered Auth Providers found matching {this.Provider ?? "any"} provider");
        res.EndRequest();
        return;
    }

    req.PopulateFromRequestIfHasSessionId(requestDto);

    PreAuthenticate(req, authProviders);

    if (res.IsClosed)
        return;

    var session = req.GetSession();
    if (session == null || !authProviders.Any(x => session.IsAuthorized(x.Provider)))
    {
        if (this.DoHtmlRedirectIfConfigured(req, res, true))
            return;

        await AuthProvider.HandleFailedAuth(authProviders[0], session, req, res);
    }
}
```

Ref. AuthenticateAttribute.cs - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d1ba794cea08d12adedf198cd10fe7cfe0a9f60e/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs

Comment: I'm not sure what `authProviders[0]` is but I was able to rewrite my method to return an async Task, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your method to have an async impl with:

```
public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    if (HostContext.AppHost.HasValidAuthSecret(req))
    {
        return;
    }

    await base.ExecuteAsync(req, res, requestDto);
    if (res.IsClosed)
    {
        return; // AuthenticateAttribute already closed the request (ie auth failed)
    }

    IronUserSession session = req.GetSession() as IronUserSession;

    if (this.HasAnyRoles(req, session))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (this.DoHtmlRedirectIfConfigured(req, res))
    {
        return;
    }

    res.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    res.StatusDescription = ErrorMessages.InvalidRole.Localize(req);
    res.EndRequest();
}
```

Comment: Maybe update docs when u have time, it is still using the .Execute(...): http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization